# Huge Run time difference in Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, windows-7-x64

I am running the following piece of code on CodeBlocks. On both platform Windows and Ubuntu I have installed the latest CodeBlocks available.

But when I execute the following code, the run time of program differs immensely. For ex, When I set K = 1000 (#Number of inputs) then on both Platform the run time is 2.7sec (Shown by the CodeBlocks console) but when K is changed to 10000 then on Windows its around 24sec and in Ubuntu its 257sec. Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    #define denominator 2
    #define getDist(a,b) exp(sqrt((a-b)*(a-b))/denominator)

    int main() {
        cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
        int K = 10000;
        int m = 10;
        //float data[4] = {1,2,3,4};
        //float dist[K*(K-1)/2];
        std::vector<float> dist(m*K);
        int count = 0;
        std::vector<float> check(m*K);

        for (int t=0;t<m*K;t++)
        {
            check[t] = (float)(rand() % 5);
            dist[t] = 0;
        }
    cout<<"Generated";
    for(int i=0; i<m*K; i++){
            for(int j =i+1;j<m*K;j++){
                int l = getDist(check[i],check[j]);

            }
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please suggest any optimizations is possible if there exists. The program should also able to scale out. As K can be K = 1000000

Comment: Before measuring times, make sure both applications are built in release mode (with optimization).

Comment: How many times have you benchmarked your program? If only once per system - it could be just a coincidence.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add an extra zero on Ubuntu by mistake ? It's a nice 10x longer.

Comment: Run the system monitor and check that one of the cores shows 100% CPU on Ubuntu.

Comment: What compilers and version of compilers are you using on each platform (note that CodeBlocks is an IDE not a compiler)?  What compilation switches are you using on each platform?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running the final loop, which has no side effects? Maybe you're actually benchmarking `rand`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I am pretty sure, Thats the final loop is running. Any particular reason for asking that ?

Comment: @skn: No particular reason, just suggesting something that might go wrong if the compiler is too clever with its optimisation. Benchmarking can be tricky, and you need to make sure you're measuring the right thing.

Comment: The both loops have no effect on program output, so a smart compiler can simply remove them.

Comment: You should always "use" the result of a benchmark (i.e. write the value to the screen, or write it to a `volatile` value. The final value of `l` is ignored, so a very smart compiler could rewrite your code to `cout<<"!!!Hello World!!!" << endl << "generated"; return 0` and get the same functionality. The simplest fix is to change `int l` to `volatile int l`, which means don't throw away the value of `l`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything "wrong". To get similar results on Linux as you describe for Windows, turn on optimization as suggested by ChronoTrigger.

Note that the math functions rand(), exp(), and sqrt() are almost certainly implemented differently by the two OSes (compilers/libraries).

```
$ g++ -O3 -pg test.cc ; time ./a.out
!!!Hello World!!!
Generated
real    0m31.878s

gprof output:
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 41.31      0.96     0.96                             main
 23.67      1.51     0.55 200000000     0.00     0.00  std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::operator[](unsigned long)
 23.67      2.07     0.55 49995000     0.00     0.00  std::sqrt(float)
  5.16      2.19     0.12 49995000     0.00     0.00  std::exp(float)
  1.94      2.23     0.05        2    22.56    22.56  std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::~vector()
...
```